# Formula of decay heat for a fraction of radioactive materials

Tags: homework-and-exercises, nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering

What is the formula of decay heat for a fraction of spent fuel? (say 50% spent fuel)

The [Wigner-Way formula](https://www.nuclear-power.net/nuclear-power/reactor-physics/reactor-operation/residual-heat/calculation-of-decay-heat-wigner-way-formula/) has not any parameter relating to the amount of fuel. Is there any other formula?

Comment: If you're going to cite some formula and ask about it, you should, at a minimum, give a source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page you link says

> It is also possible to make a **rough approximation** by using a single half-life that represents the overall decay of the core over a certain period of time. An equation that uses this approximation is the Wigner-Way formula:
> $$
> P_d(t) = 0.0622 P_0 
> \left(
>  t^{-0.2} - (t_0 + t)^{-0.2}
> \right)
> $$
>
> where
>
> - $P_d(t)$ is thermal power generation due to beta and gamma rays,
> - $P_0$ is thermal power before shutdown,
> - $t_0$ is time, in seconds, of thermal power level before shutdown,
> - $t$ is time, in seconds, elapsed since shutdown.

The emphasis on “rough approximation” is in the original. What happens is that, during fission, short-lived fission products with lots of different lifetimes accumulate towards a [secular equilibrium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secular_equilibrium). When power generation stops, the short-lived stuff dies away quickly and the long-lived stuff stays on.  If you have unspent fuel ($t_0 = 0$), this approximation says that the decay heat is always zero.

It’s not really correct to refer to this as “a single half-life” as your link does. A single half-life would go like $2^{-t/\tau_\text{single}}$.  This relationship says that, when you add up all of the half-lives of all the messy garbage that comes out of uranium fission, a time dependence of $t^{-1/5}$ captures the way that the decay radiation dies off more rapidly at the beginning than later on. It’s an empirical relationship.

You write,

> The Wigner-Way formula has not any parameter relating to the amount of fuel.

But it does: the amount of spent fuel is related to the thermal power $P_0$ while the reactor was operating.
The decay heat depends on how much fission product you have, not how much fuel you started with. [Possibly related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/292962/44126).

In a comment you ask

> Can you please tell me what is the 0.006 in the Wigner-Way formula?

There isn’t one. There is a numerical constant that’s ten times bigger than that, however.

A physicist who’s accustomed to doing dimensional analysis would be tempted to look at that factor and conclude that the decay power starts off as 6% of the thermal power. But that’s bogus, because the empirical Wigner-Way formula has screwy units. That factor $0.0622$ has dimension $\text{(seconds)}^{+0.2}$, and the exponent $+0.2$ has more to do with fitting a bunch of exponentials together that with any nice interpretable algebra. If you were to do the same kind of approximation for plutonium fuel, which has a different spectrum of short-lived decay products, you might expect a different exponent.

Answer (score -1):

There can be no general formula.
The energy released depends on the radioactive decay of each radionuclide taken one by one.
See what are the   " decay schemes   " for each radionuclide, for example for 60Co. It is different for 137Cs .
Now , if you think  " nuclear fuel"  like 235U  , one atom gives one fission which products approx  200 MeV  .
All radioactive materials are not  " nuclear fuel  " .

Comment: Thanks. Can you please tell me what is the 0.006 in the Wigner-Way formula over here https://www.nuclear-power.net/nuclear-power/reactor-physics/reactor-operation/residual-heat/calculation-of-decay-heat-wigner-way-formula/

Comment: There are several "general formulas" that can be used, with varying degrees of accuracy.  You often want to know the decay heat that a reactor generates over time, and it isn't necessary to model every single decay in every fuel rod.  Other answers refer to the Wigner formula, which is an older formula.  The most recent ANS Decay Heat Standards provide are more accurate.

Comment: @NuclearFission That would make a nice answer.